# Rails fields_for enumerate with id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fields-for

If I have a standard `fields_for` method such as:

```
<%= f.fields_for :exptypes do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'exptype_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

Is there such a way to get:

```
<%= f.fields_for :exptypes do |builder, i| %>
    <%= render 'exptype_fields', :f => builder, :i => i %>
<% end %>
```

So that a unique number (`i`) is passed to the form?

What I want to do is make unique `div` tags inside partials so I can run javascript on specific partials in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck - Rails does this already, automatically. From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html under 3.4.6 Local Variables

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called
>   by the collection, named after the member of the collection followed
>   by _counter. For example, if you're rendering @products, within the
>   partial you can refer to product_counter to tell you how many times
>   the partial has been rendered. This does not work in conjunction with
>   the as: :value option.

In your case, this is probably going to be `exptype_fields_counter`.

Comment: Thanks for that Brad. However, I'm unable to find the correct local method name. I've tried: exptype_fields_counter, exptypes_fields_counter, exptype_counter, exptypes_counter; to no avail. Is there a way to divine the name of the variable?

Comment: What is the actual object's class?

Comment: That didn't work either :(

exptype is the model itself, thus the partial is just named after it. I've noticed that other mentions of the counter reference it's use in `:collection`, because I'm not using a `:collection` and rather a loop, is it possible the counter isn't created?

Comment: Good catch, it should be pretty easy to tweak the syntax, and move the fields_for into the partial... I can't really think of a cleaner way to do it, sorry.

Comment: Could you use the object.id? It would ensure constant targetability as well as uniqueness...